# Quickspec test never gets executed successfully when the test includes an HTTP request

Tags: swift, unit-testing, alamofire, quick-nimble

I'm currently writing tests for a small part of an OSX framework I'm working on. The tests are written using the packages `Quick` and `Nimble`. The test itself is very basic:

```
class OrderbookTestKraken: QuickSpec {
    let kraken = Kraken()

    override func spec() {
        let coin = Coin(name: "DOGE", ask: 0.0, bid: 0.0, last: 0.0, bidSize: 0.0, askSize: 0.0)
        describe("When an order book is requested") {
            it("it should create an orderbook successfully") {
                self.kraken.getOrderbook(coin: coin) { (error, orderbook) in
                    expect(orderbook).notTo(beNil())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I run it, the test instantly passes. Even though there's:

1) A breakpoint in the method `getOrderbook` of my `Kraken` instance.
2) `nil` being returned in the `orderbook` variable that's being used in the `expect` statement.

The `getOrderbook` method looks like this:

```
func getOrderbook(coin: Coin, onCompletion: @escaping (Error?, Orderbook?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("\(publicApiUrl ?? "")/Depth",
        method: .get,
        parameters: ["pair": "\(coin.name)XBT", "count": 3],
        encoding: URLEncoding.default,
        headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { response in
        // There's a breakpoint here.
        onCompletion(nil, nil)
    }
}
```

So, it always returns `nil` in the callback, and there's an untriggered breakpoint, but the test always succeeds. When I tried some caveman debugging, and put a breakpoint above the `Alamofire` request, the breakpoint did get triggered.

Is this some known issue, or is It something I'm overseeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see in the console the test actually being started and passing?

Comment: @Cristik yes. It says it passes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing a `nil` as param values on `onCompletion` . Thats why always receving nil as response. Try to pass valid param values instead of `nil`.

ex:

```
onCompletion(err, params)
```